# asp.net - adding MARS to connection from web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-mars

I have this in webconfig

```
<add name="dbConn" connectionString="Data Source=PC-PC;Integrated Security=True" />
```

Then I call them most of the time in my page via

```
 string connstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConn"].ConnectionString;
```

However some page requires two queries. What I have in mind is (or what I like to achieve)

```
 string connstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConn"+"MultipleActiveResultSets=True"].ConnectionString;
```

But ofcourse it will not work. Since what stated in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf(v=vs.110).aspx) is like the code below.

footnote: I don't wanna use this in most of my page

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=MSSQL1;" + 
        "Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;" +
        "MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
```

because i have multiple pages, and of course to easily set-up the DB. 
footnote2: reason why is that because i don't know maybe it's not robust and using 2 connection in a page that only requires 1 connection maybe is ugly.
EDIT: Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two connection for your scenario :

Without `MultipleActiveResultSets=True,`

```
<add name="dbConn1" connectionString="Data Source=PC-PC;Integrated Security=True" />
```

and with `MultipleActiveResultSets=True`,

```
<add name="dbConn2" connectionString="Data Source=MSSQL1; 
        Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;
        MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" />
```

You can load above connection string as per your requirement.

Comment: Hello, I tried adding 2 `connectionstring` in the web.config but ASP doesnt allow it. I would really like that to happen (just switching the connection between the enabled and none MARS connection) but does it matter if I use MARS to a page that doesn't need mars

Comment: AFAIK, Multiple connectionstring should be allowed in web.config It would be an issue using MARS in your scenario !!!

Answer (score 0):

Load the connection string in SqlConnectionStringBuilder, manipulate the builder, then call ToString() to get the manipulated connection string:

```
string webConfigConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConn"].ConnectionString;
var builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(webConfigConnectionString);
builder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
string modifiedConnectionString = builder.ToString();
```